# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when adding first item to a BindingList DataSource

Tags: c#, datasource, bindinglist

I'm trying use a BindingList as a DataSource in C#, but whenever I try to add the first item to the BindingList, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException thrown. **In my project, I need to clear the BindingList et add new items after it has been set as the DataSource.**

```
BindingList<string> dataSource = new BindingList<string>();
myComboBox.DataSource = dataSource;
dataSource.Add("something"); // Exception, here.
```

I know the exception is handled by the .Net framework but i need to find a way to avoid it.

I also tried

```
List<DirectoryInfo> list = aList.ToList();
list.AddRange(bList);

//set the index to -1 as suggested
var index = myComboBox.SelectedIndex;
myComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

myComboBox.DataSource = null;
bindingList.Clear();
bindingList.AddRange(list.Distinct());
if (bindingList.Count > 0)
{
    //internal ArgumentOutOfRangeException here when binding
    myComboBox.DataSource = bindingList;
    myComboBox.SelectedIndex = index;
}
else
    myComboBox.DataSource = null;
```

Thanks, here is the callstack

```
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.SelectedIndex.set(int value)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.DataManager_PositionChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.OnPositionChanged(System.EventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.ChangeRecordState(int newPosition, bool validating, bool endCurrentEdit, bool firePositionChange, bool pullData)
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.List_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList<System.__Canon>.OnListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList<System.__Canon>.FireListChanged(System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType type, int index)
System.dll!System.ComponentModel.BindingList<System.__Canon>.InsertItem(int index, System.__Canon item)
######.dll!System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<###########>.Add(######### item)
```

Comment: so what happens when you change the order and assign the dataSource to the BindingList first then bind to the comboBox..?

Comment: The exception comes from the combo box. Because it is already bound to the datasource BindingList, when you ADD to the BindingList, the combo box finds that it is set to a value that isn't in the list, and barfs. So add everything you want to the BindingList first, then bind the combo box to the list, and the error goes away.

Comment: the problem is : "I need to clear the BindingList et add new items after it has been set as the DataSource." I know the exception is thrown by the comboBox we can see it in the callstack­. But swaping the line is not an available option in my project.

Comment: I think that you need to map out or draw out on paper the process that you are trying to accomplish.. it appears that you are confusing yourself with simple  logical processes in your current project explain how you are getting the data to fill the BindingList object.. then determine what conditions would arise that would cause you to have no items ...

Comment: you need to null out the datasource then.. then add to the list ..then rebind the bindinglist to the combobox

Comment: You are in a tight spot. You can create a new binding list, put the values you need into that, set the combo box index to -1 (so it won't have anything selected when you change lists), change lists, and if you like at this point, find what the old value in the combo box was using, and reset the combobox to that item's index value.

Comment: An alternative approach is to temporarily suspend updates on your Binding List when you are adding values, set the combo box index to -1 (remember what it was pointing at first if you want to restore that after the update), then have the Binding List post an "I've been updated" message to all its bound buddies. Then restore the combo box to the item it was pointed at before the update--- presuming that item still exists (its index may have changed, so it will have to be looked up).

Comment: I just updated the question with the test i did @StarPilot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, i get rid of my problem! This is the solution i found

First, i set the DataSource to null because the BindingList is always empty when i start.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = null;
```

then, when i need to update the bindingList and add some item I do something like that

```
List<DirectoryInfo> list = aList.ToList();
list.AddRange(bList);

BeginUpdate();
bindingList.Clear();
bindingList.AddRange(list.Distinct());
EndUpdate();
```

here is the BeginUpdate and EndUpdate method

```
private void BeginUpdate()
{
    //if the DataSource is going to be empty, adding the first item will
    //always trigger an ArgumentOutOfRangeException on the selected index.
    //to avoid this, we must stop the binding during the modification of the list.
    _Updating = true;
    comboBox1.DataSource = null;
}

private void EndUpdate()
{
    if (bindingList.Count > 0)
    {
        //the binding will set SelectedIndex to the old index when rebinding and it's possibily the wrong one.
        //the good index is always 0 but we set the index to -1 before to be sure to be able to trigger the
        //selectedIndex_changed method after _UpdatingRecentFolders is turn to false
        comboBox1.DataSource = bindingList;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        _Updating = false;
        //I always want 0 but you can place the index you want
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        comboBox1.DataSource = null;
        _Updating = false;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

And i also have a selectedIndex_changed event

```
private void comboBoxItem_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_Updating && comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1 )
        aControl.SelectedItem = bindingList[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
}
```

I hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this Here is an example I just tested as stated in my comment

```
var blist = new BindingList<string>();
blist.Add("something");
blist.Add("something2");
comboBox1.DataSource = blist;
```

if you need to assign it empty first then do something like this

```
if(blist.Count > 0)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = null;
    var blist = new BindingList<string>();
    blist.Add("something");
    blist.Add("something2");
    comboBox1.DataSource = blist;
}
```

do some research on `List<T>.Add` method or `BindingList.Add` method 
also look at the `.Clear()` method and the .`Count()` method

Alternative to using BindingList would be BindingSource find more reading on this topic here [MSDN BindingSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx)

Comment: you're doing `if(blist.Count > 0)` and after you create `var blist = new BindingList<string>();` this piece of code won't work as expected!